# Container extension "Security" is not registered

Tags: security, symfony, fosuserbundle

I've installed and configured FOSUserBundle and everything worked perfectly fin, until out of nowhere I refreshed my home page and then

```
Container extension "Security" is not registered
```

I've tried to clear the cache but it exits with the same exception, so I cleared the cache manually ( probably a stupid idea) and then the same exception occures.

Anyone ? Please ?

Comment: Check app/AppKernel.php and make sure you didn't accidentally delete a bundle when you added FOSUserBundle.

Comment: AppKernel.php is fine and it included the security bundle. The problem is after installing FOS everything worked fine. And when i've tried to override some views of FOS following the instructions of github, it worked, I refreshed my homepage and Whoops !